# Autopopulate Data in backend (python-Flask)

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, pandas, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a table in DB iternory_data:

[image]

Now UI can send data in any format and we want to create a JSON by auto populating the data (backward columns) and save onto s3 (UI will not handle this have to be done in backend API).

Example:
UI sends:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Here, you can see in the first row all the values till a4 are auto-populated and after that it's blank and for second row all previous column values are auto-populated.

Using: Python, Flask (API), MySQL, SQLAlchemy, pandas, numpy

I have tried through pandas, and dividing the dataframe in subset of columns (but If I do this much processing in API it would take a lot of time)
FYI, I can use pandas, numpy as well.